running wordpress in a container - ubuntu 24.04 - downloads index.php rather than serving the home page
I need to run wordpress from a container in my ubuntu 22.04 dual boot. I followed several tutorials - gradually reducing in simplicity - ie removing nginx and phpmyadmin etc - but the same problems persists. ie When I try to load the home page index.php is downloaded but the home page is not loaded. ie localhost:8080 just downloads the index.php but localhost:8080/pageX correctly loads pageX.
The exact same docker compose works perfectly on Windows. Run docker compose and hey presto it all works as advertised...
This seems to be a common problem with wordpress, but none of the online replies deal specifically with containers on Ubuntu, which is my context.
I presume its something to do with the Apache set up - but as a React/Aws dev I have no experience in this environment. I dual booted my machine so I could start working with Ubuntu, but tripping over on the first hurdle is a bad look.
Can anyone help?
Here is the file in all its simplicity and can be found at https://runcloud.io/blog/install-wordpress-on-docker
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: your_mysql_password
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: your_mysql_password
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wp_data: {}


You need to tell the web server that PHP files should be executed rather than served. I suppose you have installed PHP; then use the a2enmod command to enable the proper version of PHP.

@Jos Ok thanks Jos. You got me on the right track.  The PHP is all installed via the wordpress container and that's where the mistake was.  You need specific versions of wordpress container containing "-fpm-" in the container name, for it to be set up for nginx.

Apparently you need specific versions of the Wordpress container containing "-fpm-" in the container name, for it to be set up for nginx.
With acknowledgements to Wazoo Web Bytes tutorial Docker Setup for Local WordPress Development
The configurations below worked perfectly in both Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22:04.
nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
       index index.php index.html;
    }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}

docker-compose.yml
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8085:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - internal-network

  database:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}-database
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal-network

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - internal-network

  # you must use the -fpm- versions of wordpress because they are set up for nginx
  # try :latest and it does not work with nginx.
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - database
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}-wordpress
    image: wordpress:6.6.2-fpm-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - internal-network

volumes:
  dbdata:
  wordpress:

networks:
  internal-network:
    driver: bridge

